# MySQLi query issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

With this request:

```
<?php
$query = '
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        posts 
    WHERE 
        post_type = "post" AND 
        post_status = "publish" AND 
        post_content LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR 
        post_title LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"
';
```

I need to collect all  data from the `posts` table, with the conditions above.

Since there were no issues, I will describe what I want to do. Imagine a record is actually a *post*, has a status `publish`, and there is a match in the request in either the `post_content`, or the `post_title` fields.

As a result, I get the last two operating conditions (check on compliance in the header). And all the rest are ignored.

Comment: what is isse ? You said query works fine ! :)

Comment: The problem is that "condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 OR condition 4" is interpreted by the parser as "(c1 and c2 and c3) OR c4". where in reality you want " (c1 AND c2) AND (c3 OR c4)"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (post_type = "post" AND post_status = "publish") AND (post_content LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR post_title LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%")';
```

Comment: What did you do ? please explain

Comment: Grouping conditions so they are evaluated as one between the brackets

Comment: Just to add brackets to make the required condition work

Answer (score 0):

Just combine your LIKE clause.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE 
post_type = "post" AND 
post_status = "publish" AND (post_content LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR 
post_title LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%")';
```

You need to combine OR that means combination of two column value.